# Where is the log file for a Terminal session?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

In Terminal.app I am running zsh. I need to diagnose what went wrong when I ran a bash shell command from Terminal.app. How do I find the log file for that?

Comment: Unless the bash script did some logging on it's own there won't be any logging information about the details of its execution.

Comment: This to my eyes changed quite a bit. Are you looking to run a script with debug enabled so you can know what it’s doing without needing an IDE? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238736/why-does-set-x-cause-the-terminal-to-dump-garbage (if so, you’ll want to work with `set +x` amd `set -x`

Comment: @bmike: `set -x` does exactly what I need. Thank you.